# Error when trying to create a list of files

Tags: python, operating-system, typeerror, data-cleaning

I have a folder that contains 20 csv files. Each file has about 10 columns and thousands of rows. The csv files look something like the following:

| gene | p-value | xyz |
| --- | --- | --- |
| acan | 0.05 | 123 |
| mmp2 | 0.02 | 456 |
| mmp9 | 0.07 | 789 |
| nnos | 0.09 | 123 |
| gfap | 0.01 | 456 |

I have written the following script with the purpose of going through each file and filtering the rows only by the genes of interest that I have indicated (in this case mmp2 and mmp9).

```
# the goal is to edit and save the csv files so they only contain the genes of interest

path = '/Users/adriana/Library/Documents/raw_data',
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv")) #make list of file paths 
genes = ["mmp2", "mmp9"]
for file in all_files:
    path = '/Users/adriana/Library/Documents/raw_data'
    df = pd.read_csv(file,delimiter ='\t')
    cleaned = df[df['gene'].isin(genes)]
    cleaned.to_csv(file)
```

However, I get the following error related to creation of the object "all_files":

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

I've used this script before seamlessly, so I am not sure what is going on.

Comment: Remove the last `,` in the line `path = '/Users/adriana/Library/Documents/raw_data',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```py
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd



path = '/Users/adriana/Library/Documents/raw_data'  # Removed comma here
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))  # make list of file paths 
genes = ["mmp2", "mmp9"]
for file in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter='\t')
    cleaned = df[df['gene'].isin(genes)]  
    cleaned.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

Comment: Yep it was that comma! Only now I am getting the following error: KeyError:'gene'.